# Creating carousel from JSON response

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, carousel

I am getting a JSON response from a server which looks like this:

```
{
    "value_1": "a",
    "value_2": "b",
    "pagination": {
        "titles": [
            "Title 1",
            "Title 2",
            "Title 3",
            "Title 4",
            "Title 5"
        ]
    },
    "slides": [
        {
            "pagination_id": 0,
            "content": {
                "heading": "Welcome!",
                "description": "Stuff goes here",
                "image": {
                    "url": "<image_url>",
                    "alt": "alternative text"
                },
                "next": {
                    "label": "Next"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "pagination_id": 1,
            "content": {
                "heading": "About",
                "description": "Stuff goes here",
                "image": {
                    "url": "<image_url>",
                    "alt": "alternative text"
                },
                "next": {
                    "label": "Next"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "pagination_id": 2,
            "content": {
                "heading": "Welcome!",
                "description": "Stuff goes here",
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "label": "Group 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "label": "Group 2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "label": "Group 3"
                    }
                ],
                "next": {
                    "label": "Next"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "pagination_id": 3,
            "heading": "Welcome!",
            "description": "Stuff goes here",
            "image": {
                "url": "<image_url>",
                "alt": "alternative text"
            },
            "back": {
                "label": "Back"
            },
            "next": {
                "label": "Next"
            }
        },
        {
            "pagination_id": 4,
            "heading": "Welcome!",
            "description": "Stuff goes here",
            "image": {
                "url": "<image_url>",
                "alt": "alternative text"
            },
            "back": {
                "label": "Back"
            },
            "next": {
                "label": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "footer": {
        "legal": {
            "label": "Legal",
            "url": "<url>"
        },
        "privacy": {
            "label": "Privacy",
            "url": "<url>"
        },
        "cookies": {
            "label": "Cookies",
            "url": "<url>"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell this data is being used to create a carousel with the slide content shown on each slide. The problem I am having is that the slide titles are coming from the `pagination` part of the JSON but the actual slide content including next and back buttons are coming from the `slides` part.

Currently I have some problems:

1. I need to get the correct title for each slide.
2. I need to render buttons based on the `next` and `back` properties present in each slide.
3. When a button is clicked to go forward or back I need to keep track of the slide that should be showing.

I already know that what I need to do for part 1 is use the `pagination_id` of the slide to get the correct title from the `pagination.titles` array but I am not entirely sure about the best way to go about this.

For the second part, I think it should be possible to also use the `pagination_id` to keep a track of the current slide (I think), but I am not sure how I might go about this. I should mention that the buttons for each slide are going to be render based on the `next` and `back` properties of each slide.

This application is built with `React` and I am currently only using local state currently as I don't think that something like `Redux` is really worth including for such a small amount of data.

Any help with this conundrum would be much appreciated,

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case despite the data coming from different arrays, what you can cash around is that the number of items are the same in both arrays. So you can just use the current index of array where you are looping these items. So it would go something like this:

**Updated Code**

```
return(
 data.slides.map((slide, index)=>{
  return <div key={index}>
   <h1> {data.pagination.titles[index]} </h1> // for title
   <img src={slide.content?.image?.url || slide.image.url} alt={slide.content?.image?.alt || slide.image.alt} />
   //for buttons
   {(slide.content?.previous || slide.previous) && <button onClick={()=> setCurrentSlideIndex((index - 1) % data.slides.length)}> {slide.content?.previous?.label || slide.previous.label} </button>}
   {(slide.content?.next || slide.next) && <button onClick={()=> setCurrentSlideIndex((index + 1) % data.slides.length)}> {slide.content?.next?.label || slide.next.label} </button>}
</div>
})
)
```

Hope you get the idea.

**Update**

However if there is lot of stuff going on then you might need to make a function which gets boolean as a parameter telling whether the particular item has content object or not, and return the ui based on that conditionally. Something like this:

```
const renderSlide=(content, index)=>{
 if(content){
  return <div>
 // with slide.content.xyz
 <h1> data.pagination.titles[index] </h1>
<img src={data.slides[index].content.image.url}
 </div>
  }
else{
 return <div>
// with slide.xyz
<img src={data.slides[index].image.url}

</div>
}
}
```

and calling it inside your function as:

```
return(
 data.slides.map((slide, index)=>{
 <>
  {renderSlide(slide.content, index)}
 <>
})
```

Comment: Yeah this helped me out but I'm still having a problem handing the fact that the data I need, for both the image and the buttons, can be found in two different locations, either `slide.content.` or in some cases just `slide.`. Any idea how I might handle that?

Comment: Yes @BeeNag I have updated my answer to handle that case, code part as well as description at the end as an alternate.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working as I intended using the updated first, with a couple of added checks to make sure the correct things were rendering